# JSP passing String attribute with XML characters to JavaScript function not working

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets, jstl

I need to pass a jsp string variable to a javascript function. This is usually fairly simple but I'm currently having issues because the string I'm passing contains xml characters.

This is the jsp (shortened for clarity purpose)

```
<%@page language="java" import="java.util.*" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"   prefix="c"%>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
    <body>
        <input type="button" value="MyButton" onclick="myFunction('<c:out value="${current.xmlOutput}"/>');" />  
    </body>
 </html>
```

The value in "current.xmlOutput" contains the following

```
<chart caption='Flight Hours' xAxisName='Flight' yAxisName='Hours' ><set label='AC908' value='126' /><set label='AC812' value='234' /><set label='AC184' value='78' /></chart>
```

The generated JSP source

```
<input type="button" value="MyButton" onclick="myFunction('&lt; chart  caption  = &#039;Flight Hours&#039; xAxisName  = &#039;Flight&#039; yAxisName  = &#039;Hours&#039;&gt;&lt; label  = &#039;AC908&#039; value  = &#039;126&#039; /&gt; &lt; label  = &#039;AC812&#039; value  = &#039;234&#039; /&gt; &lt; label  = &#039;AC184&#039; value  = &#039;78&#039; /&gt; &lt;/ chart &gt;');" />
```

When I press the button it never calls the function. If "current.xmlOutput" contains a simple String like "Test" everything works fine. In the chrome developer tools it give me the following message "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier "

Also, I have a filter that does this req.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
Any one know what I'm doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out my issue was with the single quotes inside the xml. Instead of

```
<chart caption='Flight Hours'
```

it should have been

```
<chart caption=\'Flight Hours\'
```

If you're passing the string via Java/Servlet to a jsp, then you'll need this

```
String xmlToPass = "<chart caption = \\'Flight Hours\\' "
```